# airbnb/react-dates - unable to edit / type in date fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I am using airbnb/react-dates for user to select or type start and end date. However I am not able to edit date fields. I can select dates but not able to type into the date fields.

I tried reading below links but no luck so far
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates
http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DateRangePicker%20%28DRP%29&selectedStory=default&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=kadirahq%2Fstorybook-addon-actions%2Factions-panel
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/79

In my package.json I have
"react-dates": "^12.6.0"

I am using below props and running it in Chrome.

```
<DateRangePicker
        className="clientsPaging"
        displayFormat={"YYYY-MM-DD"}
        startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
        endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
        onDatesChange={this.datesChanged} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isOutsideRange={() => false}
        focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
        onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      />
```

Comment: this should be editable by default, actually a while back I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/496) about this but my request was to add a `readonly` prop to prevent typing. as far as i know it is false by default, hence you should be able to type and edit. Are you getting any errors in console when you try to type? by the way are you on mobile / touch screen or using a normal mouse and keyboard?

Comment: no errors, it just doesn't allow me to type. I am using a normal mouse and keyboard on a Mac. Browser is chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor is not visible in this version, but you could still write in the field.. 
If not, try to force `readOnly` to `false`